# Can a linear autoencoder perform projection as PCA with less layers than components?

Tags: neural-networks, pca, autoencoders

Assume that you have a matrix $X$ and you want to project it onto a subspace by using PCA. It will work. Then you are trying to use a linear autoencoder to projecting $X$ onto the same subspace. It will work too.

**Question:**

Assume that the PCA projection has $c$ components. Can a linear autoencoder project $X$ onto the subspace with the same results as PCA does, with layers $l$ that are less then components $c$?

My goal here is to create a linear autoencoder that can perform the same results, with less layers than components.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, it would seem that you would need the dimension of the subspace to be equal to both $c$ and $l$, so that $c$ and $l$ would have to be equal.

Comment: @StevenGubkin More like if a linear AE with fewer layers, can do the same as regular PCA with more components.